# How do I make a function run when a view appears, but not when an alert box is closed?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I put a function in viewWillAppear in my view controller so that it runs every time the view is loaded:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self initBasicSettings];
}
```

However, the function `initBasicSettings` is run every time a modal alert box (UIAlertView) is closed as well, which I do not want.

How do I make a function run when a view loads but not when an alert box closes? If these two events cannot be made disparate, I feel that it is not orthogonal design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is not a joke question. This method stub is inserted in new `UIViewController` subclasses by default.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Comment: Right, thanks. The thing is: `viewDidLoad` is called once no matter how many times the view is loaded. I still want the actions in `viewDidAppear` to be called every time a view is loaded. However, I do not want them to occur when an alert box is closed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by two points. 1) `viewDidLoad` *is* called every time the view is loaded. So I'm assuming you mean.. appears? pushed? 2) If I set up a sample project and present a `UIAlertView` and dismiss it I don't get any of the "appearance calls" that you seem to be getting. Perhaps some code especially where you present the alert would help. A third point, more of a side point really, in the code you posted you should be calling `[super viewWillAppear:animated]`.

Answer (score 0):

These images will clear your concept of viewWillAppear & viewWillDisappear works even when view is added to view hierarchy or removed from view hierarchy.

---

Image for view - when added to view hierarchy.

[image]

---

Image for view - when removed from view hierarchy.

[image]